# How display UISearchBar in UINavigation?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have search icon in navigation bar, and UISearchBar in TableViewHeader.
I want to hide UISearchBar but show and hide when:

**UISearchbar show**: Clicked on the search icon, then eliminate navigation and show it.

**UISearchBar hide**: Press cancel to hide search and display navigation back.

Please help me!!

Thank.

[image]

This is what I have done so far.

```
- (void) viewDidload{

self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
self.searchBar.delegate = self;

[self.searchBar sizeToFit];

self.strongSearchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;


_btnSearch = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
_btnSearch.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22);
[_btnSearch setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_btnSearch addTarget:self action:@selector(showSearch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *searchItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_btnSearch];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = _btnSearch;
}
```

This is my action when click on the iCon search

```
- (IBAction)showSearch:(id)sender{
    [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

I don't want to place my search in tableView and how still I can display UISearchBar when click on search icon?

**Another question:** when I call [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder]; it's doesn't work good. The cancel button doesn't work at all.

Please kindly help me.

Comment: If i am not wrong, in image this is [UISearchbarController](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @Virussmca
No, It's just the icon.

I want to display UISearchBar after clicked on the icon.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

to put searchBar into the center of navigationBar:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar;
```

To put searchBar to the left/right side of navigationBar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *searchBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.searchBar];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarItem;
```

As of iOS 7, the [UISearchDisplayController](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) supports this by default. Set the UISearchDisplayController's 
`displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES`

Comment: @Viruss mca
I want to display only UISearchBar and hide UINavigation.
When the UISearchBar is appeared then it hide UINavigation.
When Cancel button in UISearchBar was clicked it will eliminate it self and show UINavigation back.

Can you help me please? I need it.

Comment: @MabKaaKoo: have you check UISearchDisplayController ?

Comment: @Virussmca, I have updated my question above.
Could you please check it and help me?

Thank